# Kali Linux does not enable color profiles when I use a kvm switch

Tags: kali-linux, hardware, video

I have a computer with a generic Radeon card running Kali Linux. The install is a week old. When I plug the computer into a kvm switch cable, the only color displayed is the dark blue of the Kali install screen. Everything is dark blue, even the text inside the Terminal boxes. When I go to the Color section of Settings, Kali correctly recognizes whatever monitor I attach to the kvm switch. However, the option to change the color profile is grayed out. There is no Settings menu for the video card. If I bypass the kvm and plug the commuter directly into the monitor, or if I use RealVNC to view the desktop, the correct colors appear.
Here are the dmesg sections on the Radeon:

```
[    0.301352] smpboot: CPU0: AMD A4-3400 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics (family: 0x12, model: 0x1, stepping: 0x0)
[    2.951506] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    2.951948] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    2.951950] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[    2.952100] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO2_pfp.bin
[    2.952118] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO2_me.bin
[    2.952131] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
[    2.952227] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    2.952321] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
[    2.966232] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[    2.966234] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0x(____ptrval____)
[    2.966236] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0x(____ptrval____)
[    2.966610] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0x(____ptrval____)
[    2.966614] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    2.966658] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    2.966679] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    3.618400] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    3.706613] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.765223] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 180x56
[    3.769235] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.781482] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
```

When I use the kvm switch. there is nothing about the monitor or video in the dmesg, just entries about loading the mouse and keyboard (USB devices).
My OpenBSD and FreeBSD computers do not have this problem. Is this Kali or Linux? Is there such a thing as a driver for kvm switches? I could not find one on Google. Is there a color profile I could download that would fix the problem? And why is the color set a "Kali install blue" rather than the white color of default Terminal text? Is the number on the "color frame buffer device" too low for multiple colors?
Thanks in advance.